# How to move every three day file based on the filename to respective folders in bash

Tags: bash, files, move

I have several files like these:

```
2020.001.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.001.03.04.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.002.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.003.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.004.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.004.05.06.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.005.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
2020.006.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
...
2020.366.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
```

The files are year.day.hour1.hour2... The important parameters are the year and day. The day goes from 001 to 366 (or 365).

What I want is to organize my files like this (folder and files). So create the folder and move the respective files into it:

```
2020.001.003 - 2020.001.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.001.03.04.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.002.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.003.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac

2020.004.006 - 2020.004.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.004.05.06.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.005.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
               2020.006.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
```

and so on until finishing the files in day 366

What I did (which does not work as I want):

```
for file in *.sac
do
year=`echo "$file" | awk -F"." '{print $1}'`
day=`echo "$file" | awk -F"." '{print $2}'`
dayi=$day
dayf="366"
#
# Moving every three day files
delta=2
x1=$dayi
x2=$(echo "$x1+$delta" | bc)
if [ $x1 -lt $x2 ]
then
echo $x1 $x2
dir=$(echo "$year"."$x1"."$x2")
mkdir $dir
x1=$(( x1+3))
x2=$(( x1+delta))
fi
done
```

As a result the code is creating folders like:

```
2020.001.3
2020.002.4
2020.003.5
...
```

Basically it is creating folders that I do not need. Also I still do not know how to move the files into the folders.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything can be done much simpler if using bash's abilities:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.sac
do
    year=${file:0:4}
    day=${file:5:3}
    
    range_start=$(( (($day-1)/3)*3+1 ))
    range_end=$(( $range_start+2 ))
    
    ndir=$(printf "%04d.%03d.%03d" $year $range_start $range_end)

    mkdir -p archive/$ndir
    mv $file archive/$ndir/
done
```

Comment: White Owl, thanks a lot for your help. This works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Just let me add, in case anyone need this code, because I have a 008 day and this is an octal number, a slightly change needs to be made in the range_start: range_start=$(( ((10#$day-1)/3)*3+1 )).

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, you could do it using its `zmv` batch renamer.

```
autoload -Uz zmv
mkmv() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"; }
zmv -n -P mkmv '(<->.)(<1-366>).*.sac' \
               '$1${(l[3][0])$(( start = ($2 - 1) / 3 * 3 + 1 ))}.${(l[3][0])$(( start + 2 ))}/$f'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

That gives:

```
mkmv 2020.001.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.001.003/2020.001.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.001.03.04.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.001.003/2020.001.03.04.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.002.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.001.003/2020.002.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.003.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.001.003/2020.003.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.004.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.004.006/2020.004.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.004.05.06.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.004.006/2020.004.05.06.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.005.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.004.006/2020.005.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.006.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.004.006/2020.006.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
mkmv 2020.366.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac 2020.364.366/2020.366.00.01.pcc1_TBTZ_TBTZ_1.0-3.0.sac
```